# How do you Serialize just one of several Optional Elements in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I have a class with two parameters. One is the update time in Minutes and the other is the same value in seconds like this:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[XmlRoot(ElementName="config")]
public class Config
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "update_mins")]
    public int Minutes 
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Seconds / 60;
        }
        set
        {
            this.Seconds = value * 60;
        }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "update_secs")]
    public int Seconds { get; set; }
}
```

I get xml strings that can have either update_mins or update_secs but not both. I need to be able to use this class to deserialize these strings, this works ok. I also need to be able to searalize these classes and send them on, however when I do the serailzation it includes both update_secs and update_mins. Like this:

```
<config>
  <update_mins>23</update_mins>
  <update_secs>1380</update_secs>
</config>
```

When I want to get this:

```
<config>
  <update_secs>1380</update_secs>
</config>
```

I tried putting XmlIgnore on the update_mins value, but that stopped it deserializing the element. Is it possible to do this, and if so how?

My full code example is:

```
namespace Scrap
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "<config><update_mins>23</update_mins></config>";

            XmlSerializer searializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Config));
            Config result = (Config)searializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(s));

            Console.WriteLine("Minutes: " + result.Minutes);
            Console.WriteLine("Seconds: " + result.Seconds);

            Debug.Assert(result.Minutes == 23);
            Debug.Assert(result.Seconds == 1380);

            StringWriter s2w = new StringWriter();
            searializer.Serialize(s2w, result);

            Console.WriteLine(s2w.ToString());

            string xmlResult = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>\r\n" +
                "<config xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">\r\n" +                
                "  <update_secs>1380</update_secs>\r\n" +
                "</config>";

            Debug.Assert(s2w.ToString() == xmlResult);

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "config")]
    public class Config
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "update_mins")]        
        public int Minutes
        {            
            get
            {
                return this.Seconds / 60;
            }    
            set
            {
                this.Seconds = value * 60;
            }
        }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "update_secs")]
        public int Seconds { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The only way to do this in a declarative way is to create another class with the same properties that you use for deserialization.  So you can apply [XmlIgnore] on the original.  The code smell of getting a truncated Minutes value in regular code should give you some pause.

Comment: I know that the minutes value will be truncated, however I need to do this for bacwards compatibility with an old system and lossing 59 seconds isn't going to be that big an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is still not an ideal solution, but the way I have resolved this is to add [XmlIgnore] to the Minutes property (as Aliostad and others had suggested) and then add an AllElements property like this:

```
    [XmlAnyElement]
    public XmlElement[] AllElements
    {
        get
        {
            XmlElement[] value = new XmlElement[0];
            return value;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                foreach (XmlElement e in value)
                {
                    switch (e.Name)
                    {
                        case "update_mins":
                            this.Minutes = Convert.ToInt32(e.InnerText);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use `[XmlIgnore]` on `Minutes` since it is

- Dependent on the Seconds
- Calculated field
- Redundant in data transfer

---

## EDIT

You are mentioning that you do not have control over which element gets populated and it could be either or both.

One possible solution is to add one layer of abstraction.

- Define internal public properties such as `SecondsXml` and `MinutesXml` and let them read XML values (Define attributes on them)
- Keep `Minutes` and `Seconds`
- have a boolean fields `_isLoaded`
- Whenever `Minutes` or `Seconds` accessed, check `_isLoaded` and if false, then check values in `SecondsXml` and `MinutesXml` to figure out which one was loaded hence set `Minutes` and `Seconds` accordingly.

If you do not want to have `SecondsXml` and `MinutesXml` as public, define them as private but use [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) for deserialization.

Comment: Make sure you put the attribute on the property, NOT on the class.

Comment: I tried that and it stoped desearializing if the messages comming in only had the minutes element.

Comment: Well, as I said, `Minutes` should not be in deseralized. It is a calculated property.

Comment: Sounds to me like you don't understand what my issue is. I don't get to control whether the incomming XML messages have minutes or seconds, so I have to deal with both cases. Your answer just won't work for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
class Config : IDeserializationCallback
{
    void IDeserializationCallback.OnDeserialization(object sender) 
    {
    }
}
```

or

```
class Config
{
    [OnDeserializing]
    void OnDeserialization(StreamingContext context) 
    {
    }
}
```